# Issue with FilePicker in BlackBerry 10

Tags: blackberry-10

I've being trying to implement a native File picker on BlackBerry 10 today, I linked it against the required Library `-lbbcascadespickers`
Included `<bb/cascades/pickers/FilePicker>` that links to the FilePicker.hpp class and all seems fine, but when I try to create a new File picker it says "error: 'FilePicker' was not declared in this scope"

Code is as follows:

```
    FilePicker* filePicker = new FilePicker();
filePicker->setType(FileType::Picture);
filePicker->setTitle("Select Picture");
filePicker->setMode(FilePickerMode::Picker);
filePicker->open();

// Connect the fileSelected() signal with the slot.
QObject::connect(filePicker,
    SIGNAL(fileSelected(const QStringList&)),
    this,
    SLOT(onFileSelected(const QStringList&)));

// Connect the canceled() signal with the slot.
QObject::connect(filePicker,
    SIGNAL(canceled()),
    this,
    SLOT(onCanceled()));
```

I'm brand new to BlackBerry development so don't really know what to do, I've cleaned the project and built it many times but it won't play.
I was going by the example on BlackBerry's website:

[https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb_*cascades*_pickers__filepicker.html](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__pickers__filepicker.html)

I wanted to open it from QML (I'm using Qt Quick and not BB components)

If anyone can help it will be deeply appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler can't find FilePicker.  So either use a using to tell the compiler where to look:

```
using namespace bb::cascades::pickers;
```

or fully qualify the name of the class:

```
bb::cascades::pickers::FilePicker* filePicker = new FilePicker();
```

Comment: I tried to fully qualify the class name but it now says the following,
 "../src/Utils.cpp:17:54: error: expected type-specifier before 'FilePicker'
../src/Utils.cpp:17:54: error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'bb::cascades::pickers::FilePicker*' in initialization
../src/Utils.cpp:17:54: error: expected ',' or ';' before 'FilePicker'
../src/Utils.cpp:18:22: error: 'FileType' has not been declared
../src/Utils.cpp:20:22: error: 'FilePickerMode' has not been declared"

How would tell the compiler where to look? Never had this kind of trouble before.